# Why does single LSTM output not appear in return_sequence output?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I am trying to understand how LSTM models work, specifically the use of the return_sequences parameter in keras' LSTM layer. As a simple example, referring to the code below, I sort of understand that `LSTM(1)` "outputs a single hidden state for the input sequence with 3 time steps" [[1]](https://machinelearningmastery.com/return-sequences-and-return-states-for-lstms-in-keras/) and that `LSTM(1, return_sequences=True)` "returns a sequence of 3 values, one hidden state output for each input time step" [[1]](https://machinelearningmastery.com/return-sequences-and-return-states-for-lstms-in-keras/).

However, my understanding of that means that the single output from `LSTM(1)` is correlated to each time step, as per the functionality of recurrent networks, meaning that the final output from `LSTM(1, return_sequences=True)` should be the same as the single output from `LSTM(1)`?

As an example, referring to the below code, I don't understand why the final output from model 2's predictions does not equal the output form model 1's? I was further confused when running the same code below with just a single value/time step and it also produced two different results. I think my confusion comes from mixing up multiple cells with multiple time steps, but it's still just not clicking in my brain. Any clarity on this would be very much appreciated!

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM
import numpy as np

# one feature per 3 time steps
data = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3]).reshape((1,3,1))

# Input + a single LSTM (two versions)
input = Input(shape=(3,1))
lstm1 = LSTM(1)(input)
lstm2 = LSTM(1, return_sequences=True)(input)

model1 = Model(input, lstm1) # without return_sequences
model2 = Model(input, lstm2) # # with return_sequences

print(f'Model 1 without return_sequences:\n {model1.predict(data)}\n\n')
print(f'Model 2 with return_sequences:\n {model2.predict(data)}\n\n')
```

Returns:

```
Model 1 without return_sequences:  
[[-0.13452706]]
    
Model 2 with return_sequences:  
[[[0.01917788]   [0.05195162]   [0.09362084]]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured it out. I was correct in assuming that the final output from `LSTM(1, return_sequences=True)` should be the same as the single output from `LSTM(1)`, but I was getting different results due to the random seed! The results were equal to each other after setting the random seed before each of the LSTM layers like so:

```
# Input + a single LSTM (two versions)
input = Input(shape=(3,1))
tf.random.set_seed(2)   # <-----
lstm1 = LSTM(1)(input)
tf.random.set_seed(2)   # <-----
lstm2 = LSTM(1, return_sequences=True)(input)
```

Double checking:

```
model1.predict(data)[0] == model2.predict(data)[0][-1] # returns: True
```